# Insert a rule to a script on a new line

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote the following script that asks for input and then writes this to a file.

```
^1::
 InputBox, text, fire writing, What did you achieve today?
 file := FileOpen("log.txt", "w")
 file.write(text) 
 file.Close()
```

return

This works. However, Im looking for two other things:

- Text should be added instead of replaced.
- After each input Im need a new line. So I have input "A" and "B" the result should be:

A
B

Any comments on how I should change this code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- [Flag](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileOpen.htm#Flags) "w" creates a new file, overwriting any existing file.
- Use "a" (Append) to append text to a file, creating the file if it didn't exist.
- Once the file is opened in append mode, use `file.Write(text "`n") to
  add a new line after appending the  text:

This way:

```
^1::
     InputBox, text, fire writing, What did you achieve today?
     file := FileOpen("log.txt", "a")
     file.write(text "`n") 
     file.Close()
 return
```

Answer (score 0):

For writing one liners you can also use the [FileAppend command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm).
You can add new lines to the text by using **`n**

```
^1::
     InputBox, text, fire writing, What did you achieve today?
     FileAppend, %text%`n, log.txt
 return
```